# Bellman ford single source shortest path for adjacency matrix not detecting negative cycle

Tags: c++, c++11, shortest-path, bellman-ford

I have tried implementing Bellman ford Single Source Shortest Path for adjacency matrix, but it is not detecting one of the vertices in the negative cycles

the same algorithm works for edge list, but gives error in adjacency matrix

This is what the graph looks like:
[image]

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#define INF INT_MAX
#define NINF INT_MIN

void shortestpath(int src, vector<vector<int>> &matrix){
    int N = matrix.size();
    vector<int> dist(N, INF);
    vector<int> prev(N, 0);

    dist[src] = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k < N-1; k++){
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
                if(dist[i] != INF && matrix[i][j] && dist[j] > (dist[i] + matrix[i][j]) ){
                    dist[j] = dist[i] + matrix[i][j];
                    prev[j] = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    //     if(i != src)
    //         cout << src << " - " << i << "\t" << dist[i] << endl;
    // cout << "\n\n";

    // to check if -ve cycles exist or not
    for(int k = 0; k < N-1; k++){
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
                if(matrix[i][j] && dist[j] > (dist[i] + matrix[i][j]) ){
                    dist[j] = NINF;
                    prev[j] = -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        if(i != src)
            cout << src << " - " << i << "\t" << dist[i] << endl;
    return ;
}

// Driver function
int main(){
    int V = 8;
    vector<vector<int>> matrix(V, vector<int>(V, 0));
    matrix[0][1] = 1;
    matrix[1][2] = 1;
    matrix[2][4] = 1;
    matrix[4][3] = -3;
    matrix[3][2] = 1;
    matrix[1][5] = 4;
    matrix[1][6] = 4;
    matrix[5][6] = 5;
    matrix[6][7] = 4;
    matrix[5][7] = 3;

    shortestpath(0, matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
0 -> 1   =   1
0 -> 2   =  -2147483648
0 -> 3   =  -3
0 -> 4   =  -2147483648
0 -> 5   =  5
0 -> 6   =  5
0 -> 7   =  8
```

there is a -ve cycle at 2->4->3, but my code only detects 2 and 4

Comment: thank you @TedLyngmo

Comment: Thank you for the information @TedLyngmo , i have edited accordingly

Comment: Great, you're welcome! What kind of debugging have you tried? Did you use a real debugger or try to print out the values inside your functions to see where it goes awry? The latter is usually good enough to debug small programs.

Comment: `for(int k = 0; k < N-1; k++){` it seems to me that this should go to N-1 (note the strict less-than there) (update: if this fixes your problem let me know and I write it in an answer  so it can be closed properly)

Comment: i tried it, still gives wrong solution @JuanR

Comment: @TedLyngmo i tried printing out the values, that's how i came to know that the values for one of the vertexes in the negative cycle doesn't changes, 
But as mentioned in the answer below, that it was due to unspecified behavior of adding a -ve number to -ve infinity, now i can see, that the values for the vertices with -ve weight wasn't changing it's value in the 2'nd looping due to this behavior of -ve infinity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second loop, `dist[i] + matrix[i][j]` may exhibit unspecified behavior by way of integer overflow if `dist[i]` is already set to `INT_MIN` and `matrix[i][j]` is negative. In practice, the sum wraps around to a large positive number, and then the condition `dist[j] > (dist[i] + matrix[i][j])` doesn't hold, and `dist[j]` is not updated.